# Creating git feature branch using teamcity

Tags: git, teamcity, git-flow, feature-branch

I want to create git feature branch using teamcity and also merge it to dev using teamcity. Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

Just like do it in shell. Except you should specify repository directory by `git -C /path/to/repository <command>`.

First you need ensure the working directory turn into what you expected. So just use `git reset --hard` to ignore potential errors.

Second you need carefully deal the merge operation, it needs success. So you should choose how to resolve conflict. `git merge help` has explained in MERGE STRATEGIES section. I suggest to use `recursive theirs` to preserver feature branch changes.

Example:

`git -C /home/git/test checkout master
git -C /home/git/test reset --hard origin/master
git -C /home/git/test checkout -b newfeature
do some change
git -C /home/git/test add -A .
git -C /home/git/test commit -m "Do some change"
git -C /home/git/test checkout master
git -C /home/git/test merge -s recursive -X ours newfeature
git -C /home/git/test push`

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. But i want to achieve this through teamcity. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Add build step `command line` in TeamCity. And copy paste these comand.

Comment: Ok what about creating the feature branch? Example, If I have some 5 repos in project, and I want to create a feature branch, then from Teamcity through any configuration/script I should be able to create same feature branch in all the repos at once.

Comment: The first three lines of code is about to create feature branch. You need to know where feature branch starts and then create branch based on that, like: `git checkout -b newfeature basedCommitOrBranch`

Comment: Just create new feature branch for every repository. After that run any script you use.
Why do you need create feature branch? I think continuous deploy doesn't need that.